# javascript and jquery lab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery with my JavaScript code I created (interactive dictionary). I'm not sure what is the best approach, please advice.

JS file:

```
'use strict';

     let myDictionary = {
    "Determinant": "Noun [C] FORMAL - Something that controls or affects what  happens in a particular situation: Soil and climate are the main determinants of how land is used.",
    "Enthusiasm": "Noun - A feeling of energetic interest in a particular subject or activity and an eagerness to be involved in it: I just can't work up (= start to feel) any enthusiasm for the whole project.. ",
    "Passionate": "Having very strong feelings or emotions: a passionate speech The child's mother made a passionate plea for help. Joe is passionate about baseball (= he likes it very much)..",
    "Consistency": "Noun - (BEING THE SAME) the quality of always behaving or performing in a similar way, or of always happening in a similar way: They've won a few games this season but they lack consistency. It's important to show some consistency in your work. Opposite inconsistency (inconsistent).",
    "Powelessness": "Noun - The condition or feeling of having no power: A significant cause of stress in the workplace is a sense of powerlessness and lack of control. As hostages, they experienced humiliation and utter powerlessness.."
    }; 


    let buttonListElement = document.getElementById("buttons");
    let definitionElement = document.getElementById("definition");

    function createOnClickListener(definition) {
    return function() {
        definitionElement.innerHTML = definition;
       }
    }

    for (let word in myDictionary) {
    let buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    buttonElement.innerHTML = word;
    buttonElement.addEventListener("click", createOnClickListener(myDictionary[word]));
    let listItemElement = document.createElement("li");
    listItemElement.appendChild(buttonElement);
    buttonListElement.appendChild(listItemElement);
 }
```

Comment: How are you wanting to use it?

Comment: I use this .js code with html file and css file. I want to use jquery in the .js file.

Comment: So include jQuery in the html file before the inclusion of this js file, and then you can use it. [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: I know I have to dowalod jquery and link my html to the jquery file. But, also I have to edit my javascript file too!!

Comment: Right.  But if you are asking a question like, now that you included jQuery, how do you convert what you have to using jQuery, I'm going to have to tell you that that is too broad of a question.

Comment: [learn.jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com) covers the basics for people just starting out with jQuery, and is a great place to being learning.  And the StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info page also has useful information and links as well

Comment: That right, my problem is how to convert all my code to something that use jquery.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a translation service.  You have to learn that yourself, and ask specific questions about what you do not understand.  Asking for translation makes this too broad.

Comment: Thank Taplar you for the link, I'll check them and I hop I'll find some helpful information.

Comment: I asked for help, if the way may question was formatted wasn't clear I apologize but you don't have to be so offensive towered me. It my first time using StackOverflow and I feel like I'm in the wrong place to ask for help!! I hop that StackOverflow community isn't about embarrassing someone who asked just a question!?

Comment: You are not wrong to ask for help, but it is our duty as helpers to explain to users, especially new users, when they are misunderstanding how the site is used, and what questions we look for.  If you took that as offensive, I apologize.  Much of this information, regarding the questions we look for, is included in the [ask] section and might also be helpful for you to take a quick read of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning jQuery so I've been stepping through my code I posted and I'm trying to change everything over.I've already converted the js to jQuery, I want to know if there is any other change can be added to the code.

```
enter code here

$(document).ready(function() {
  let myDictionary = {
  "Determinant": "Noun [C] FORMAL - Something that controls or affects what happens in a particular situation: Soil and climate are the main determinants of how land is used.",
  "Enthusiasm": "Noun - A feeling of energetic interest in a particular subject or activity and an eagerness to be involved in it: I just can't work up (= start to feel) any enthusiasm for the whole project.. ",
  "Infinity": "Time or space that has no end. A number that is larger than all other numbers.",
  "Love": "To like another adult very much and be romantically and sexually attracted to them, or to have strong feelings of liking a friend or person in your family.",
  "Noun": "A word that refers to a person, place, thing, event, substance, or quality." 
 }; 

 let buttonListElement = $('#buttons');
 let definitionElement = $('#definition');

 function createOnClickListener(definition) {
  return function() {
     $(definitionElement).html(definition);
   }
 };

 for (let word in myDictionary) {
   let buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
   $(buttonElement).html(word);
   buttonElement.addEventListener("click", createOnClickListener(myDictionary[word]));
   let listItemElement = document.createElement("li");
   listItemElement.append(buttonElement);
   buttonListElement.append(listItemElement);
  }

});
```